# Unblock an my IP from Google Compute Engine after failed sftp attempts

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine

We have recently setup a new Google Compute Engine VM machine and while in the process of setting up Filezilla to SFTP into the instance my IP has been blocked.

We have installed Wordpress on the instance and I can access it from the office and mobile phone but not home.

We haven't setup any security or firewalls at the moment so I am unsure where to go to unblock my IP.

Any assistance would be great.
Machine type - g1-small (1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory)

I am able to access other instances that we have set up from home - just no this particular one.

Many thanks,
Spencer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an issue only Google can assist with, as it is account (IP) specific. Contact Google Support directly via the contact links on their pages.

Comment: Hello, you should ask on https://www.serverfault.com, stackoverflow is more orientated towards code issues and software development.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix this issue myself - my ISP must have black listed it.

I stopped and restarted my VM, then updated the Cloud DNS with the new IP Address and then was able to access the site.